# Javascript Represent an integer as any string

Tags: javascript

I need help representing an integer as any string of my choice (not just the actual string representation of the integer).

Context- I have a dropdown box on a web app consisting of numbers placed into an array `[10, 5, 0, -5, -10]`. On the web application I need the `0` to appear as the string "Select", but still maintain the functionality of the int `0`. There may be an HTML or CSS solution to this if it is not possible in JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use key value pairs?

Comment: In coding what you have tried? Just update your question with your code

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp?

Comment: You should definitely elaborate on your specific question. You can cast anyway you like and interchangeably use operands of any type: `''+123 == '123' && ~~'123' === parseInt('123',10)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question here

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dropdown (i.e. `select` element), the `value` attribute of the `option` elements are independent of the text displayed to the user.

You can have an

```
<option value="value that you want to have in code">
    Text that your user should see
</option>`
```

If the select needs to be populated from an array, then you can use JavaScript to create DOM elements and add them to the corresponding `select` node.

HTML

```
<select id="selectbox"></select>
```

JS

```
array.forEach(function(e) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = e;
    option.textContent = e ? e : 'Select';
    document.getElementById('selectbox').appendChild(option);
});
```

Should generate

```
<select>
  <option value="10">10></option>
  <option value="5">5></option>
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="-5">-5></option>
  <option value="-10">-10></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that if you want "Select" to be the first item in the dropdown you should change the order of your array to have `0` first.  If you just want it to be default, but still in the middle (with + numbers above it, - numbers below), use the `selected` attribute on the `0` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value property of the options:

```
<select id="my-select">
   <option value="0">Select</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="-5">-5</option>
</select>
```

Javascript to get current value:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('my-select');
var myValue = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```js
var selectValues = [10, 5, 0, -5, -10];
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
     if(value==0){
       $('#cars')
         .append($("<option ></option>")
         .attr("value",value)
         .text("Select")); 
     }else{
       $('#cars')
         .append($("<option ></option>")
         .attr("value",value)
         .text(value)); 
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <select id="cars" name="cars">
    
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery was not specified

Comment: If all they need is to create a select, jQuery is huge overkill and has a learning curve for this obvious noob.